# Send data via http to android web service

Tags: android, http

I have to send data via http to android web service.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you;

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you search on the [Google?.](http://www.google.co.in/#pq=android+post+data+to+server&hl=en&sugexp=pfwc&cp=13&gs_id=m&xhr=t&q=android+send+data+to+server&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=android+send+data+to+server&aq=0&aqi=g1g-b1&aql=f&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=2d139cb8296ff9f2&biw=1280&bih=688) Also Look on this discussion, [Post data to the server.](http://www.coderanch.com/t/471150/Android/Mobile/Post-data-Server) It will help you.